# How to get the week day name from a date in Apache pig?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

Given "03/09/1982" how can we say it is which week day. In this case it will be "Tue".

Is it possible to get in a single query?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can convert this string into date object using [ToDate()](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/func.html#to-date), then again into string with desired format using [ToString()](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/func.html#to-string), and dont forget that Pig uses Java [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) class to deal with dates.

```
ToString( ToDate('03/09/1982','dd/MM/yyyy'), 'EEE' )
```